# Optimize PHP Function and SQL Queries to extract dependent data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

If I have two tables with their respective columns:

- product_catrgories: id, name
- products: id, category_id, name

And I have the following PHP functions:

- `function getProducts() { ... } // Returns an array of all rows from the products`
- `function getProductCategory($category_id) { ... } // returns the corresponding row to the given id of the product category`

Currently, I am displaying a list of all products in a table with the following headings:

- id
- Category
- Name

Where category is the name of the category corresponding to the category_id of the product.

Currently I am using a foreach loop to iterate through the product and calling the getProductCategory(...) function for each product:

```
<?php
...

$products = getProducts();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_category = getProductCategory($product['category_id']);
    ...
}

...
?>
```

Which would be an extensive amount of queries to the database if there are lots of products with many repeated queries.

Is there a way I can optimize this operation?

Comment: Can you "eager load" the data using a `JOIN`?

Comment: @tadman Then that would mean that I would have to modify the `getProducts() { ... }` function in which the query would also return the category information?

Comment: Presumably. If this is a custom-made ORM then you're going to have to reinvent more wheels. If it's an existing one I'd look at how it handles eager loading. If you're not in too deep yet maybe you can switch to a well-supported ORM that does this for you out of the box.

Comment: @tadman It is all custom made an yes, I have already programmed most of the functions that queries the database. But are you referring to using a pre-build framework?

Comment: There's a number of ORMs out there like [Idorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm),
[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/),
[RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), and
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to name but a few. They vary in terms of sophistication and how much you have to commit to using them, but it's worth looking first to see if switching to that is easier than continuing down the pure custom road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I decided to use eager loading through the use of `SQL JOIN` statements for example I would get the ids of all the products and use `WHERE id IN(...)` in my sql query:

```
<?php
$products = getProducts();
$product_ids = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_ids[] = $product->id;
}

$product_categories_data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM products_categories WHERE id IN(?, ?, ?, ..., ?)', $product_ids);
?>
```

Then performing the rest of my operations on the results.